# discord bot sends infinite messages regardless of user input

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot respond when someone makes laughing remarks but it infinitely sends gifs whenever someone types anything
code is as follows

```
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
import keep_alive
Bot_Token = os.environ['Bot_Token']
bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  guild_count = 0

  for guild in bot.guilds:
    print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")
    guild_count = guild_count + 1

  print("AGOP_Bot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "AGOP~hello":
    await message.channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/tTXwGpHrqUcAAAAC/summoned.gif")

  if message.content == "Lmao" or "Lol" or "lmao" or "lol" and message.author.id != bot_id:
response_funny = ["https://c.tenor.com/mUAgLfICUC0AAAAC/i-didnt-get-the-joke-abish-mathew.gif","https://c.tenor.com/zdoxFdx2wZQAAAAd/not-funny-joke.gif","https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/53/97/f55397a7de1c82b37d6d62e655a0e915.gif","https://jutsume.com/images2/2022/04/16/is-this-some-peasant-joke-meme.png","https://c.tenor.com/FnASqUdvJH4AAAAC/whats-so-funny-john.gif"]
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(response_funny))

bot.run(Bot_Token)
keep_alive.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
# import keep_alive
Bot_Token = os.environ['Bot_Token']
bot = discord.Client()
...
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "AGOP~hello":
    await message.channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/tTXwGpHrqUcAAAAC/summoned.gif")

  if message.content in ("Lmao" or "Lol" or "lmao" or "lol") and message.author.id != bot.user:
    response_funny = ["https://c.tenor.com/mUAgLfICUC0AAAAC/i-didnt-get-the-joke-abish-mathew.gif","https://c.tenor.com/zdoxFdx2wZQAAAAd/not-funny-joke.gif","https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/53/97/f55397a7de1c82b37d6d62e655a0e915.gif","https://jutsume.com/images2/2022/04/16/is-this-some-peasant-joke-meme.png","https://c.tenor.com/FnASqUdvJH4AAAAC/whats-so-funny-john.gif"]
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(response_funny))

bot.run(Bot_Token)
# keep_alive.py
```

In addition to some formatting, I changed some of the variables for the API calls. I commented out the keep_alive.py as I assume you are using that to keep your code hosted on Repl.it or something, and you can just comment it back in. I was also able to get this code to work with my bot and execute as you want.